# Flux doesn't pick up podLabels

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, flux

I'm adding istio to an existing cluster which is managed by flux. A really old version. That might be the issue. Flux is using helmrelease. I'm trying to add app and version labels to helmrelease. I found it in the documentation: podLabels: {} So I've just added the following:

```
values:
  podLabels:
    app: appname
    version: appversion
```

And of course flux doesn't do anything with it.
(EKS 1.20 and Flux 0.29.0)

I've modified the helmrelease file and flux didn't do anything. I did a crosscheck and modified something else in that file and that worked. Only podLabels is not working.